# reading signed ints from openCV in/to libtorch tensor c++

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

I have a cv::Mat which is CV_32SC3 type, it stores both positive and negative values.

When convert it to tensor, the values are messed up:

```
cout << in_img << endl;

 auto tensor_image = torch::from_blob(in_img.data, {1, in_img.rows, in_img.cols, 3}, torch::kByte);
```

The in_img has negative values, while after print out tensor_image, the values were all totally different than in_img.

the negative values are gone (it somehow seems to normilise it 255 range). I tried converting to Long like so:

```
auto tensor_image = torch::from_blob(in_img.data, {1, in_img.rows, in_img.cols, 3}, torch::kLong);
```

but when I print the values like so, I get seg fault:

```
  std::cout << "tensor_image: " << tensor_image << " values." << std::endl;
```

so, I tried looking at just the first element like so:

```
std::cout << "input_tensor[0][0][0][0]: " << tensor_image[0][0][0][0] << " values." << std::endl;
```

and the value is not the same as I see in the python implementation :((

Comment: To clarify, in the above example, `in_img` is of type `cv::Mat`?

Comment: yes Pranav. thats right. When I use at::kByte to read it in, it is all fine.. expect that the values seems scaled, which I do not want (I want the original mat matrix which contains both + and - values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `32SC3` means that your data are 32bits (4 bytes) signed integers, i.e `int`s. Pytorch `kByte` type means `unsigned char` (1 byte, values between 0 and 255). Therefore you are actually reading a matrix of ints as if it were a matrix of uchars.

Try with

```
auto tensor_image = torch::from_blob(in_img.data, {1, in_img.rows, in_img.cols, 3}, torch::kInt32);
```

The conversion to `kLong` was bound to fail because `long` means `int64`. So there are just not enough bytes in your opencv `int32` matrix to read it as a `int64` matrix with the same size.

Comment: OMG - seriously, genius stuff.. Thanks a tonne. Would have never figured this out by myself :rolling_eyes ps: love your id.